# Including JavaScript at runtime is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript

The below piece of code was working in IE6 & IE7 and almost all versions of FF. It just don't work in IE8. It doesn't work in the sense once I added the script tag in to HTML->HEAD element I don't see the script being loaded in the browser(the alerts in the script doesn't show up). I see the  tags have been inserted in the HTML-HEAD though.

```
var head = document getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
// Check if the script is already loaded.
if (head ){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.language = 'JavaScript';
    script.src = '/Tolven/scripts/' + jsFileName;
    head.appendChild(script);       
}
```

Does anybody have this issue? Or any clues to resolve this?

Comment: Which framework and version are you using? (`$$` is not a native JS method).

Comment: It's prototype.js, I changed the question to use JS method now.

Comment: Are you getting some error message in ie8?

Answer (score 1):

If this script is in `<head>` tag than head does not exists when this script is parsed and executed. So, of cource `if (head)` is `false`.

Your are using JS framework -- so feel free to use it's tools. And also do not forget to include Your framework, before using it.

```
<!-- if your are using mootools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    // Your code...
  });
</script>

<!-- if your are using prototype -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    // Your code...
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This script is run when I try to call a JS method which is in .js file. Before running the JS method I'll check if the script is not included and include it if it's not. For sure <head> is there when this code is running. I also mentioned that the I see the script tag included in the HTML. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a library like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [LABjs](http://labjs.com/) that do the job of including scripts at runtime really well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var head = document getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

should be

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
```

Script seems to work after this modification.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I was using prototype for querying DOM, I replaced $$() call with a JS method.

Answer (score -1):

This is was actually working. There is was an error(it only happens in IE8) in one of the scripts that's inserted at runtime. Eventually it's not executing alerts in the pages loaded next. Thanks for your answers though.